# Secret key is there though it is saying no secret key in django

Tags: python, django

When i'm running python manage.py runserver or python manage.py migrate. I'm getting these errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder(object):
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 23, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 24, in Migration
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1081, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/sroy8091/college/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

This is my development settings

```
"""
Django settings for kgecweb project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret key here'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
#DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'administration',
    'stdimage',
    'dept',
    'trplc',  # Training and Placement app
    'faculty',
    'student',
    'hostels',
    'nkn',
    'clibrary',
    'page',
    'contact'




)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kgecweb.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kgecweb.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.mysql'),
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '713331',
        'HOST': '192.168.33.19',
        'PORT': '3306',
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../static"),)


#STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I also have made the sql command for initializing database and secret key is also not empty here. Though it keep on saying. i don't know how to tackle this.
This is my project directory
[image]

I even tried making a settings.py file then also this error is coming.

Comment: Set `SECRET_KEY` to a long (about 30 characters) random string.

Comment: I have 30char long secret key in settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then try:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=kgecweb.settings.development
```

I guess your didn't use the build-in setting.py or you rename it or make a directory to handle different settings.py.

#### EDIT

- Make sure your project in your  python path, use this to find out.

  ```
  import sys
  print(sys.path)
  ```
- or you can just create a settings.py in kgecweb(the app) then run

  ```
  python manage.py runserver
  ```
- if it works, you just try:

  ```
  python manage.py runserver --settings=kgecweb.settings.development
  ```

Comment: Yes there are two setttings file one for production and one for development

Comment: If your settings file put in a directory call settings, you should try:  python manage.py runserver --settings=your_project.settings.your_real_settting.py

Comment: yes i have settings folder in which there are two files development.py and production.py. when i tried python manage.py runerver --settings=kgecweb.settings.development.py    It is saying no module named development.py

Comment: still coming no module named development.py

Comment: python manage.py runerver --settings=kgecweb.settings.development, if still not working, please post your project directory

Answer (score 0):

From the vanilla `settings.py` you can specify what settings to do by setting an environment variable to tell settings which to use. For example.

Suppose you have an env variable called DJANGO_ENV='prod' then in your settings.py

```
import os

environment = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ENV', 'dev')
if environment == 'prod':
     from project_folder.production_settings import *
else:
     from project_folder.development_settings import *

#rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

You **misspelled** the name of the file.

change

```
devlopment.py
```

to

```
development.py
```

and everything should work with calling the file directly