# Override settings from another Django app

Tags: python, django

How can I in my project settings.py override a setting from an apps settings.py?

I tried importing it like this:

```
import app.settings
EXTENSIONS = {
    'Folder': [''],
    'Image': ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.tif', '.tiff', '.svg'],
}
```

**But I get an error:**

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting
>   must not be empty.

How can I override settings from another app?

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217362/secret-key-is-there-though-it-is-saying-no-secret-key-in-django/39217496#39217496

Answer (score 0):

Your SECRET_KEY is empty or missing in settings.py file.

Add random generated SECRET_KEY to settings file.

For example:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=6x$7smkllimrwa@j+d7(tr%i=3cax!bz+0vyje%$!gj+*dvd4'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
from app.settings import *
```

The goal is to import the settings into the module namespace.